# An answer to a wrong question: flag was declined

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, declined-flags

A user posted [an answer to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415328/combining-union-and-limit-operations-in-mysql-query/14869506#14869506) (now deleted) in which he asked a totally different question. Some time later, he posted [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415328/combining-union-and-limit-operations-in-mysql-query/14869890#14869890) where he gave an answer to his question.

I flagged his question with the following custom message:

> This user posted both his question and an answer (as answers) in this question, so delete both of them.

The flag was marked as helpful. The question was deleted (as an obvious non-answer). However, the answer was *not* deleted.

So, I decided to flag the answer with the following custom message:

> This is an answer to a totally different question that this user asked as an answer to this question (the question was deleted as non-answer but this answer is still here).

However, this flag was *declined* with the following reason:

> flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I disagree with this decision because the answer is wrong in a different sense: it doesn't attempt to answer the original question. Technically, it is an answer - but to a question that has been deleted as non-answer.

Shouldn't the answer be deleted too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I agree so I deleted the answer.  It looks like two different moderators (and n00b ones at that!) handled your flags, so the streams got crossed.  It's fixed now, and I'll let them know.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Crossing the streams would be bad.